# Indicator - Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

To each event $A$ in a probability space $(S,P)$
we associate a random variable (called the indicator of $A$)
as follows: $I_A:S \rightarrow R$ where $\forall s\in S$
we have

$$I_A(s) = \begin{cases} 1&\text{if}~s\in A \\ 0&\text{otherwise}.
                  \end{cases}$$

Prove the three statements are equivalent:

$A$ and $B$ are independent.

$I_A$ and $I_B$ are independent.

$E(I_{A\cap B})=E(I_A)E(I_B)$.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ and $B$ are independent $\iff P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)\iff E(1_{A\cap B})=E1_AE1_B$

Now you can just show that $$
1_{A\cap B} = 1_A1_B
$$

Now as the indicators take only two values, then this is equivalent to 
$1_A,1_B$ are equivalent.

Comment: Could you please show how you made this conclusion: $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)\iff E(1_{A\cap B})=E1_AE1_B$. Also, did you mean to say $E(I_{A\cap B})$?

Comment: yes, this is what I meant. for the first question, this is just $P(A) = E(1_A)$

Comment: how do you know that?

Comment: this is a definition actually

Comment: Should it be $E(1_A)E(1_B)$ instead of $E1_AE1_B$ ?

Comment: This is precisely what I mean.